# How to get KClass of generic classes like BaseResponse<Iterable<User>>

Tags: kotlin

If I try to get

```
BaseResponse<Iterable<User>>::class
```

I get error error only classes are allowed on the left hand side of class literal. I have searched and still not found how to get generic classes's type in kotlin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't -[`KClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html) can only describe the class `BaseResponse`, and you can get a `KClass` instance that does that with `BaseResponse::class`.

What you have however, `BaseResponse<Iterable<User>>`, is a concrete type, which you can be represented as a [`KType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type/index.html) instance. `KType` instances can be created, for example, with the [`createType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/create-type.html) function. This would look something like this:

```
// User
val userType = User::class.createType()
// Iterable<User>
val iterableOfUserType = Iterable::class.createType(arguments = listOf(KTypeProjection.invariant(userType)))    
// BaseResponse<Iterable<User>>
val responseType = BaseResponse::class.createType(arguments = listOf(KTypeProjection.invariant(iterableOfUserType)))
```

I made the choice of making the type parameters both invariant, there's also factory methods in [`KTypeProjection`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type-projection/index.html) to create covariant or contravariant types, as you need them.

Comment: You can then use responseType.javaClass to get the actual Class<T> from KType

Comment: @JuanCarry This is incorrect. It will Give you `Class<KType>`. To achieve that, you could do `responseType.classifier as? KClass<BaseResponse<Iterable<User>>> ` (and handle the unchecked cast)